# geom_boxplot: map alpha levels to whiskers & outliers

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to make `geom_boxplot` lines, whiskers, and outlier points inherit the same `alpha` that is assigned to the boxplot `fill` in the following plot?

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, alpha = Species == "setosa")) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.5, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: you might want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601194/change-colours-to-defined-palette-for-ggplot-objects) from earlier today

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a natural way to do it within `ggplot2`, but here's a hacky way: The colour aesthetic determines the colour of the lines, whiskers, and outlier points. So we'll add a colour aesthetic to the plot. However, we'll set the colors manually so that they include the sequence of alpha values in the color definitions. As a result, we effectively add alpha values to the color aesthetic. I've mapped the aesthetics to `Species` so that I can have three different alpha levels for illustration and added `theme_bw()` for better contrast of the alpha values.

First, set the alpha values we want in the final graph:

```
numVals = length(unique(iris$Species))
avals = seq(0.9, 0.3, length.out=numVals)
```

Here's the hack: Set the all the colors to black, but add the alpha-level sequence to the color definition. For this, we need to convert the the alpha levels to hexadecimal on a 0 - 255 scale.

```
avalsHex = paste0("#000000", toupper(as.hexmode(round(avals*255))))
```

In the code above, `avals*255` are the alpha levels on a 0 - 255 scale. `as.hexmode` converts those values to hexadecimal. `toupper` isn't strictly necessary, but I'm used to seeing hexadecimal color definitions in upper case. Then we paste the two-digit hexadecimal alpha value onto the end of the color, in this case black (`#000000`), which gives a vector of three colors that include alpha values.

No we plot with both the color and alpha aesthetics and the manual values for each aesthetic:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color=Species, alpha = Species)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = avals) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = avalsHex)
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** To address your comment, here's an example with different colors in addition to alpha values:

```
avalsHex = paste0(c("#FF0000","#00FF00","#0000FF"), toupper(as.hexmode(round(avals*255))))
```

Then just run the same plotting code to get:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** Thinking about colors made me realize that you don't even need the conversion to hexadecimal to add on the alpha values. For example, with `hcl` colors you can do this:

```
# Black boxplots with 3 different alpha levels
scale_colour_manual(values = hcl(0,0,0, alpha=avals))  

# Colored boxplots with 3 different alpha levels
scale_colour_manual(values=hcl(seq(15,375,length.out=4)[1:3], 100, 65, alpha=avals))
```

The `hcl` function returns the hexdecimal code for each color, in effect taking care of the conversion for you.

Comment: Not as hacky as I'd feared!

If I had a vector of different fill colors (i.e. not all starting at `#000000`), would this method still work? (sorry, that first sentence got prematurely published)

Comment: Well, it does maintain the spirit of `ggplot`'s grammar, but you have to go outside the normal ggplot workflow to make it work.

Comment: To answer the rest of your comment: Yes. You can tack any alpha level you want onto any hexadecimal color by adding the additional two hexadecimal digits. See update for a simple example.