# Can you stack boxplots in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

This is an example of my plot. Notice how the boxplots are next to each other. I want to figure out if there is a way to stack the box plots on top of each other.
[image: example plots]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by stack them on top of each other? Do you have an example image showing what you want? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: If you put `position = "identity"` inside `geom_boxplot`, they won't be "dodged". This will put them on top of each other and likely make them illegible.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**
Because it was a challenging task I got a little further:
The main hint was in the comments of Gregor Thomas. I searched a little and found this [geom_boxplot: map alpha levels to whiskers & outliers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618517/geom-boxplot-map-alpha-levels-to-whiskers-outliers)

The result:
Plot A can be shown as plot B with the code below:
[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

df <- diamonds

# defining individual alpha levels
# learned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618517/geom-boxplot-map-alpha-levels-to-whiskers-outliers
numVals = length(unique(iris$Species))
avals = seq(0.1, 0.4, length.out=numVals)

avalsHex = paste0("#000000", toupper(as.hexmode(round(avals*255))))

# the plots with some data tweaking
p1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(color = fct_lump(color, 2),
         mutate = fct_reorder(color, depth)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cut, depth))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=color, alpha=color)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = avals) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = avalsHex) +
  theme_void()

p2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(color = fct_lump(color, 2),
         mutate = fct_reorder(color, depth)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cut, depth))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=color, alpha=color), position = "identity") +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = avals) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = avalsHex) +
  theme_void()

plot_grid(p1, p2, labels = "AUTO")
```

**First answer:**
I am not sure, but you can achieve a kind of stacking with `coord_flip`.
See my example with diamonds dataset. This means to just show the boxplots without the dots.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = depth, fill = color)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]