# Modify viridis palette in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to color a ggplot by a factor that's mostly numerical, like so:

```
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = cut(Petal.Length, 0:7))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_viridis_d()
```

What I would like to do is to special-case the `(0,1]` value and color that in red but to retain the viridis gradient for the remaining values. I know I could [change the color on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601194/change-colours-to-defined-palette-for-ggplot-objects) but I wonder if it's also possible to construct a new discrete color palette that has red as its first color and the gradient thereafter, which would make the code a bit more re-usable.

The more general question is therefore: **Can one easily add/remove/edit the colors in an existing discrete color palette?**

Comment: To which package does `scale_color_viridis_d` belong?

Comment: `scale_color_manual(values = c("red", viridis::viridis(6)))`?

Comment: D'oh, that was _way_ easier than I thought. @seasmith, you want to submit that as an answer?

Comment: On second thought: Is there also a way of doing this for a continuous palette?

Comment: For a continuous scale, I think you would need to make the call to `continuous_scale()`; build your custom color scale function and pass it to the `palette` argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically the same as @seasmith's answer, except with the addition of saving the palette to a variable to use later. I do this often for explicitly setting a `NA` color and then using the palette across multiple plots.

Other packages have similar functions to the `viridis` ones: for example, you can get ColorBrewer palettes from `RColorBrewer::brewer.pal`, CartoColor palettes from `rcartocolor::carto_pal`, or any of the `ggthemes` ones from functions with the same name as the palette.

```r
library(tidyverse)

plasma_pal <- c("red", viridis::plasma(n = 6))

plasma_pal
#> [1] "red"       "#0D0887FF" "#6A00A8FF" "#B12A90FF" "#E16462FF" "#FCA636FF"
#> [7] "#F0F921FF"

iris %>%
    ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = cut(Petal.Length, 0:7))) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_manual(values = plasma_pal)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

Requires a call to `scale_color_manual()`

```
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = cut(Petal.Length, 0:7))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", viridis::viridis(6)))
```

[image]