# Omit Brighter colors on RColorBrewer palette to use in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to use the darker colors in the "Oranges" palette in RColorBrewer to use in my ggplot (bargraph). I however am unable to. Help. Below is the sample code:

```
my_palette = brewer.pal(n = 9, "Oranges")[4:9]


### Bar Plots ###
ggplot(Sample_df, aes(x = Sample_Score), fill = Sample_Score) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "count", width = 0.8) + scale_fill_brewer(palette= my_palette)  + scale_y_log10(labels = comma) +
   labs(title="Distribution of customers according to Sample Score",x="Sample Score", y="Number of Customers") +
     theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 10),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 8),  
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 8), legend.position="none")
```

Comment: We don't have `Sample_df`. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Not an exact dupe, but very close to one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49905139/5325862

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you are using `scale_fill_brewer()`. This command expects an `RColorBrewer` palette name. (e.g. `"Oranges"`). It cannot read your custom palette name `my_palette` Instead, use `scale_fill_manual()`

I created an own reproducible example:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot)

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x=runif(10,0,1), y=runif(10,0,1), c=factor(sample(1:5,10,replace=T)))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point(aes(color=c)) + scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Oranges')
```

As you can see, I am calling the `RColorBrewer` palette `"Oranges"`. As you mentioned, these coloured are very light, and you may want to use only the darker ones. To do this, you can make a custom palette and call it using `scale_color_manual()` (or `scale_fill_manual()` in your case) instead of `scale_color_brewer()`.

```
my_palette <- brewer.pal(name="Oranges",n=9)[4:9]

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point(aes(color=c)) + scale_color_manual(values = my_palette)
```

This will now use the colors you specified in `my_palette`

Comment: Thanks for this.
FYI, the scales package has a wrapper function, ```scales::brewer_pal```, around RColorBrewer.
```scales::brewer_pal(name = "Oranges")(9)[4:9]``` achieves the same outcome.