# How to select certain colours from a colour palette in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a bar plot similar to this in ggplot:

[image: Light image]

But I cannot easily see the lightest colour bars on projectors.

I would like to skip the lightest colour blue in the "Blues" palette and instead use colours 2:9 or 3:9 for plots.

I have used the iris dataset as an example:

```
df <- data.frame(iris,petal.colour=c("red","blue"), country=c("UK","France","Germany"))

ggplot(df, aes(petal.colour,Sepal.Length))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",aes(fill=country))+
  facet_wrap(~Species, ncol=3)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues" ,
                    labels = c("French Flower", "German Flower","UK Flower"))+
  theme_bw(base_size=18)
```

It seems the common fix is to make the background darker, but this would look out of place with my other images and is therefore not an option. It is important I am also able to rename the legend, as the example.

Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify viridis palette in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905139/modify-viridis-palette-in-ggplot)

Comment: `RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, 'Blues')` gives the vector with all nine colors from 'Blues'

Comment: To clarify, in the question I marked as a duplicate, we were adding a color to the palette. In your case, you're removing a color. But it's the same working with adding or removing elements of a vector

Answer (score 9):

Here's one approach, where you predefine the palette as being the last 3 colors of a four-color Blue palette:

```
my_colors <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(4, "Blues")[2:4]

ggplot(df, aes(petal.colour,Sepal.Length))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",aes(fill=country))+
  facet_wrap(~Species, ncol=3)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors,
                    labels = c("French Flower", "German Flower","UK Flower"))+
  theme_bw(base_size=18)
```

[image]